# Can we retrieve the Dynamic URL after the first time app installation using Firebase Dynamic Link? if yes, then how? (Swift/iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

**Step1**: - Click on the URL link

**Step2**: - If the app is not installed then go to the app store OR play store.

**Step3**: - After installing the app the first time open it.

**Step4**: - **How to get the referral(Dynamic) URL. (Is it possible to get the URL the first time open the app from the app store OR play store)**

> ***Reference*** : https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/user-to-user
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/rewarded-referral

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Open Dynamic Links in your app**

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive

> 1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLBjAg6HvG0

> 2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSC5ed6OowA

> 3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqCi-TaUfJs

[image]

[image]